# Is there a way to find and display a Rhyming word for a JAVA program?

Tags: java

I have made a JAVA program which tries to find words that rhyme with the word "glow". The program looks through the poem "in flanders field", and should output any words that rhyme with glow. For this, I tried to get it to look for words that end with "ow" but instead of displaying the rhyming words, it just displays "ow". TO sum it up, I want the program to look over the poem, and display all the words rhyming with "glow" using the find, match, or capture methods.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class juspractice {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("ow", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

    String s = "In Flanders fields the poppies blow\n" + 
            "Between the crosses, row on row,\n" + 
            "    That mark our place; and in the sky\n" + 
            "    The larks, still bravely singing, fly\n" + 
            "Scarce heard amid the guns below.\n" + 
            "\n" + 
            "We are the Dead. Short days ago\n" + 
            "We lived, felt dawn, saw sunset glow,\n" + 
            "    Loved and were loved, and now we lie,\n" + 
            "        In Flanders fields.\n" + 
            "\n" + 
            "Take up our quarrel with the foe:\n" + 
            "To you from failing hands we throw\n" + 
            "    The torch; be yours to hold it high.\n" + 
            "    If ye break faith with us who die\n" + 
            "We shall not sleep, though poppies grow\n" + 
            "        In Flanders fields ";

    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What about "dough"? And "ago"?

Comment: @DaveNewton Shh

Comment: Yes, but the word dough isn't in the poem, so for now I'm opting for the program to just find words that end in "ow" (row,  grow, throw...)

Comment: In any case, your regex pattern is "ow", so that's all that'll match. I'd suggest 10-15 minutes of a regex tutorial (or better web searching for "regex find words matching pattern" or something). The dividends of self-directed learning outweigh platter-fed answers.

Comment: There's a method in the String class called lastIndexOf.  The Javadoc can be really helpful.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: I'll check that out, thanks! @GilbertLeBlanc

Comment: no need for regex. you can revert the words with `new StringBuilder(hi).reverse().toString()` then sort them, then check for first letters matching for your first letter which is `w`, then for `o` ... in a loop. voila!

Comment: you pattern matches only `ow`. you need to change it, like `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w*ow", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);`

Comment: Thanks! @davenewton

Comment: How can I actually output the words that rhyme. Like I would write "System.out.println(*What should i write in here in order for the rhyming words to be displayed*)"

Comment: @kofemann I did this, and it is only outputting the first rhyming word. How can I get it to output all of the rhyming words throughout the text?

Comment: I would try with: `\\b\\w+ow\\b` as regexp, i.e. \b begin of word \w+ at least one character before "ow" and then another word boundary. For the record, bookmark a useful website to test your regexp: https://regex101.com/

Comment: @kekolab Got it, thank you! Program is working good now!

Comment: @learnerprogramer, you can find all the words and not only the first one substituting your `if(m.find())` with `while(m.find())`: here the relative javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29

Comment: don't forget "foe"

Answer (score -1):

To simplify the program, you can download a text file "In Flanders Field".
Here's the file: https://www.ndrs.ca/uploads/In%20Flanders%20Fields%20Poem.pdf

After downloading, you can save the file in your local file system.
For Mac, you can copy and paste the file's location. To get the file location, you can click the Get Info button on the file by right-clicking the file. When you see the where section, you have to copy the information that is inside it.
The catch statement is for printing out a code block when there is an error. To learn more about try and catch in java, you can visit here: [https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_try_catch.asp#:~:text=The%20catch%20statement%20allows%20you,occurs%20in%20the%20try%20block](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_try_catch.asp#:%7E:text=The%20catch%20statement%20allows%20you,occurs%20in%20the%20try%20block).

Here's the code for your question:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.Buffer;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class juspractice {

public static void main(String[] args) {
try {
    File file = new File("Your file location");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("ow", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    int count = 0;
    String s;
    while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        while (m.find()) {
            ++count;
            String [] rhyme = s.split(" ");
           for (String i : rhyme) {
                 m = p.matcher(i);
                 if (m.find()) {
                    System.out.println(i);
                 }
            }
        }
    }
    br.close();
    System.out.println(count + " matches found");
} catch (IOException e) {
System.err.println("Cannot read file: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, this answer mainly focuses on reading file contents, rather than address the problem described by OP. Reading from a file is irrelevant to the question. You should instead explain how this code solves OP's problem.

Comment: Are you trying to read a pdf as plain text here?